# Wordpress & Gravity Forms - Why Is My For Only Display Form Admin & Not Post Author On FrontEnd?

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I'm building a directory listings website where local businesses can add and edit their listings from the front-end of the website. I'm running into an issue where only administrators are able to view the form on the front end, but the listing author can't. Here is my conditional code:

```html
<?php if(current_user_can( 'edit_others_posts', $post->ID ) || ($post->post_author == $current_user->ID))  { ?>

<?php
 echo do_shortcode('[gravityform id="17" update=" '. $post->ID . '" title="false" ajax="true" description="false"]');

?>

<?php } ?>
```

I was able to find a fix yesterday. Apparently, to allow front-end edits to listings - you have to hook into a gravity forms settings and tell it to do so. Otherwise, non-admins won't be able to view the form.

```html
// Allow gravity form editing on the front end
add_filter('gform_update_post/public_edit', '__return_true');
```

Comment: What doe you get when you `var_dump($current_user);`?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the debug suggestion. I'll make sure I keep it handy for any future issues I may run into. 

Apparently, by default - gravity forms has front-end post editing disabled to the public, which I assume includes any user role other than administrators. I added the filter that fixed my issue in the OP. 

Thanks for your tip again!